# ActionScript 3.0 namespaces, embedding & library classes

Tags: actionscript-3

I have two Flash projects - projA and projB. both of them have a FLA, some objects in theyr respective libraries that can be instantiated (export for ActionScript) and many AS files.

Now I would like to use projB inside projA. I could simply copy over all projB AS files to the projA folder and merge the libraries.

However - i'd prefere to keep the projects in theyr own folders and use namespaces instead.
So I set for all as files in projB the namespace to "projb".

Now i can import those classes into my projA by using import projb.MyClass.

This works. However - the problem is that those class files from projB don't find the Classes which were created automatically by 'export for actionscript' anymore (those defined within projB.fla).

I get the error:

```
1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: SomeClassNameDefinedInLibraryOfProjB.
```

so I tried to embed projB.swf using

```
[Embed ( source = "ProjB.swf")] //this is in the file MyClass.as on line 12
```

however - this gives me the error

```
C:\Projectfiles\ProjA\projb\MyClass.as, Line 12 'C:\Projectfiles\ProjA\projb\ProjB.swf' results in generated code, cannot use existing class 'projb.MyClass'
```

as well as:

```
Unable to transcode ProjB.swf
```

how to do this correctly?
thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify embedding symbol. For example:

[Embed ( source = "ProjB.swf", symbol = "ProjB" )]